# Фильтрация строки в JS при помощи регулярных выражений

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Какой паттерн нужно написать, чтобы на выходе получить, например, строку `15, 43, 54, 2, 1, 23, 1, 6`? То есть нужно заменить все символы (в том числе и пробелы) на `, -`, и чтобы запятые при этом не повторялись.

```
var str = '15,43,54, 2, 1л23а1-4 6';
var myPattern = /\D/g;
var strА = str.match(myPattern); //паттерн, который должен вернуть 15, 43, 54, 2, 1, 23, 1, 6
console.log(strА);
```

Comment: У вас патерн верный. Вам надо split+join `strA=str.split(myPattren).join(",")`

Comment: Вы не поняли вот щас я получаю к примеру : из 15,43,54, 2,ы4 6 ффффф  - 1,5,4,3,5,4,2,4,6  А я хочу получить 15,43,54,2,4,6  , НО ВСЕ РАВНО СПАСИБО

Comment: Вам ответ уже дали, да надо + доставить в шаблон

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой вариант. Каждая последовательность символов отличных от цифр заменяется на запятую:

```js
var str = '15,43,54, 2, 1л23а1-4 6';
var myPattern = /\D+/g;
var strА = str.replace(myPattern, ','); // патерн который должен вернуть 15, 43 , 54, 2, 1, 23, 1, 6  
console.log(strА);
```

Comment: ВСЕМ БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО !!!!!! ПРЯМ я очень БЛАГОДАРЕН !!!  Щас оформлю как отдельную функцию и буду радоваться !!!!